# Polynomial division to function multiplication on ODE with Separable Method

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

I want to solve the ODE below with the Separable Method. I know I need to see the product of $f(y)$ and $f(x)$, but I don't remember the algebra needed to see it on the polynomial division:

$$\frac{dy}{dx} =\frac{ xy + 3x -y -3 }{ xy -2x + 4y -8}$$

Comment: Is the numerator $xy+3x\color{blue}{-y}-3$ ?

Comment: Yes, my mistake.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume $dy/dx = \frac{xy + 3x-y -3}{xy -2x + 4y -8}$

numerator: $xy + 3x-y -3$.

The product of the linear factors, in general, is $(x+a)\cdot (y+b)$. Multiplying out gives: $xy+ay+bx+ab$

Now you can compare the coefficients:

$a=-1,b=3$ and $ab=-3$.

Thus $xy + 3x-y -3=(x-1)\cdot (y+3)$

Answer (score 0):

The thing to observe is that both the denominator and numerator can be factorized to linear factors.

$(xy+3x-y-3)=(y+3)(x-1)$ and $(xy-2x+4y-8)=(y-2)(x+4)$

Hence we can write the equation as $\int \frac{y-2}{y+3} dy = \int \frac{x-1}{x+4} dx $ to obtain the answer $\frac{e^y}{|y+3|^5}=C \frac{e^x}{|x+4|^5}$ where $C$ is arbitrary.